# You're importing a component that imports react-dom/server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, email, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am having the following error when I use the react-email package in my next.js project the problem is caused by the Tailwind component so when I comment it out it works but since I want to apply some classes to style my email any way I can get around  this would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules\@react-email\tailwind\dist\index.mjs
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that imports react-dom/server. To fix it, render or return the content directly as a Server Component instead for perf and security.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry "use client":
  ./node_modules\@react-email\tailwind\dist\index.mjs
  ./email\contact-form-email.tsx
  ./actions\sendEmail.ts
```

contact-form-email.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    Html,Body,Head,Heading,Hr,Container,Preview,Section,Text
} from '@react-email/components';
// import {Tailwind} from '@react-email/tailwind'

type ContactFormEmailProps = {
    message: string;
    email: string;
}

export default function ContactFormEmail({message,email}: ContactFormEmailProps) {
  return (
    <Html>
    <Head />
    <Preview>New message from your portfolio website</Preview>
    {/* <Tailwind> */}
        <Body className="bg-gray-100 text-black">
            <Container>
                <Section className="bg-white borderBlack my-10 px-10 py-4 rounded-md">
                    <Heading className="leading-tight">You received the following message from the contact form.</Heading>
                    <Text>{message}</Text>
                    <Hr />
                    <Text>The sender's email is: {email}</Text>
                </Section>
            </Container>
        </Body>
    {/* </Tailwind> */}
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Comment: But what does `@/lib/utils` import? Because if that's a catch-all utils file, good bet that either directly or indirectly imports `react-dom/server`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i add `@/lib/utils` file to the question so that you can see it has not caused the issue.

Comment: Then the next action is going to have to be turning your code in a [mcve], so that you can show enough code in your post that folks can copy, and see reproduce the same error (although it's entirely possible that while forcing yourself to form that MCVE, you're going to find the error already)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so, what are you saying, make it clear. I already give the necessary code?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is to read the [mcve] article, and then applying that to your case by further reducing the fairly large amount of code you're showing into a single, small, piece of code that still reproduces the problem. You're currently showing a number of files because you don't know where the problem is. Running through the MCVE exercise helps with that (it helps with that so well, in fact, that it usually makes you discover the problem on your own, no longer needing folks on SO to help. But in the rare cases that doesn't happen, the now minimal code is perfect for putting in your post)

Comment: please carefully read my question from top to bottom, I now what caused the error and in fact I mentioned it at the very top, I guess you do not seem to read it and you  think it is caused by `@/lib/utils`,so i provided it to show you it did not caused the error. Then why I provided other files here because as you might have guessed it I needed to show every body how they use the  `contact-form-emial.tsx`  file so that it is clear.

Comment: No, I'm not, I want you to [edit] your post to focus _on that_: if you know it's the tailwind component, then show the smallest possible bit of code that _shows that happening_ to folks who copy-paste that code. E.g. a single self-contained `App` that does nothing except show an `<h1>` or something, imports tailwind, and shows that error happening when we copy your code and run it. If it is what you say, then none of the code you're currently showing are necessary, but a [mcve] is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just mark them as external packages.

```
const nextConfig = {
    ...,
    experimental: {
        ...,
        serverComponentsExternalPackages: [
            '@react-email/components',
            '@react-email/render',
            '@react-email/tailwind'
        ]
    }
};
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverComponentsExternalPackages

Comment: sorry for late replay, I was having some hardware issue with my pc. Indeed it works.

Comment: First I tried adding this to my main project's next.config, and it didn't work. I had to specifically add it to the next.config of the .react-email folder, that's generated when running `pnpm email` for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade `react-email/tailwind` to `^0.0.8`. I encountered this when I used the latest version `react-email/tailwind`.

Comment: Note that this is more of an anecdote than an answer: _why_ should folks downgrade? EI.e. what changed in the newer version(s) to cause this, and do you have links to issues that talk about that, or even official docs, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You should add reactServerComponents in the next.config.js file

```
  reactServerComponents: {
use: ["@react-email/tailwind"]}
```

and then you can use your tailwind element in your component

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because your eslinting rules are applying nextjs lint errors to your email templates when your email templates don't really need nextjs linting rules.

You can add 'use client' to the top of the file where you are importing @react-email/tailwind and that will remove the error. Or you can disable the eslint rule for that one file.

Comment: i already tried to use  'use client'  directive on `contact-form-email.tsx` but that does not work since i am importing and using that client component in sendEmail.tsx which is a server component because i am using serverActions which is not possible.please tell me how could i disable the eslint rule for that one file

Comment: Any luck on this?